# Converting java code in C#. Operator error

Tags: c#, java, operators

I'm working on one project. Converting java code in C#. How to convert following java code in C#.

```
int h4; 
int e = h4;    
int[] w = new int[80]; 

e += 1518500249 + (a << 5 | a >> 27) + (b & c | (b^ 0xFFFFFFFF) & d) + w[0];
```

Show compiler error at line 4 "Cannot implicitly convert type long to int".

Comment: Wondering Don't you get Use of unassigned variable h4 error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just changing the type of your variables from `int` to `long`?

```
long h4;
long e = h4;    
long[] w = new long[80]; 

e += 1518500249 + (a << 5 | a >> 27) + (b & c | (b ^ 0xFFFFFFFF) & d) + w[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is 'e' declared? Is it of type 'int'?
If so, change it to 'long' and debug from there

EDIT: nevermind, i see - the calculation results in a 'long'.
The compiler sees that and tells you that you cannot implicitly convert that 'long' to an'int'

using 'long' will fix this

Comment: It's on the very first line.